# How to ignore the case sensitivity in List<string> while calculating of an index of an entry

Tags: c#

Let us say I have this code:

```
private readonly static List<string> ExtPos = new List<string> {".dat", ".wef"};

private static int ExtToPos(string ext)
{
    return ExtPos.IndexOf(ext /*, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase*/);
}
```

How can I ignore the letter case in content search?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could use [FindIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0k601hd9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
int ix = ExtPos.FindIndex(x => ".DAT".Equals(x, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Or you could use the [StringComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): it's more "resistant" to `null` (note how I built the previos comparison: I put the "100% not-null because it's a fixed string" value on the left of the `Equals`!)

```
int ix = ExtPos.FindIndex(x => StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase.Equals(".DAT", x));
```

Comment: FindIndex works perfect, thank you! (I got String.Compare(ext, x, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0 as predicate)

Comment: @Georg Using `Compare` and then `== 0` feels a bit wrong. It is better to use `Equals` in that case (it returns a `bool` right away). You could consider using `OrdinalIgnoreCase`. The default for equality checks with strings is an ordinal comparison, so if you want "equality like usually, only case-insensitive", you might prefer `OrdinalIgnoreCase`.

Comment: That's right, Compare == 0 looks a bit strange, "Equals" is much better for those applying.  "CurrentCultureIgnoreCase" I unfortunate taken from xanatos, usually I use the faster ordinal-comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [FindIndex method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(System.Collections.Generic.List%601.FindIndex);k(SolutionItemsProject);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true). Like this:

```
private static int ExtToPos(string ext)
{
    return ExtPos.FindIndex(_ => 
        string.Equals(_, ext, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
}
```

Comment: In which of framework version? I'm using .NET 4.0 and there is no possibility to pass a lambda function to the IndexOf function.

Comment: @Georg: Sorry. It should have said `FindIndex`. I've updated my answer.